# Find number of subsets, that xor of remaining numbers equals 0

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, xor

Given n numbers, find minimum number of subsets, such that xor of remaining numbers is equal to 0. For example:

`{1,1,3,4,5}`

result is equal to 3, because we can delete subsets {1,3} (in two ways) or {3,4,5}.

I'm searching for something faster than O(2^n) brute-force.

This is a duplicate of that question:
[Find number of subsets, that xor of remaining numbers equals to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33718953/find-number-of-subsets-that-xor-of-remaining-numbers-equals-to-0)

But the answer which was marked by OP is really unclear. Could you re-describe that? Or just add something by yourself.

Comment: You should post this as an comment on the accepted answer.

Comment: Could you? There are needed rep points, which new users doesn't have at start.

Comment: may also be related to [algorithm - Increase set of numbers so that XOR sum is 0 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14199255/increase-set-of-numbers-so-that-xor-sum-is-0?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating my previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33719182/3315583):

**Input** : Array a of size n such that `1 <= a[i] <= m`

**Output** : Number of subsets such that xor of set of remaining numbers is zero. Notice that this is equivalent to number of subsets whose `xor = X where X = xor of all elements of a`

Consider your example,

`X = XOR({1,1,3,4,5}) = 2`
Verify that, `XOR({1,3})=2` and `XOR({3,4,5})=2`

where `XOR(set)== XOR of all elements of set`

**Solution** :

Consider [Dynamic Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) table of size n*m.

`D[i][j] = #subsets considering first i elements of a whose xor is j`

Now to calculate the table, you need to define following recursive relation:

`D[i][j] = D[i-1][j] + D[i-1][j xor a[i]]`.

**Intuition / Proof:**

You need to calculate number of subsets of first i elements whose xor is j. Focus on ith element a[i],

a[i] is not present in subset => any subset of `i-1` elements whose xor is j will be valid

a[i] is present in subset => any subset of `i-1` elements whose xor is `j xor a[i]` is valid. This is because when we add a[i] to this set, we have `j xor a[i] xor a[i] = j`. So the xor of new set is j.

**Answer:** Finally you have filled up the entire table. Your answer is `D[n][X]` as you need those subsets whose xor is X.

PS: If you are still confused, I suggest you go through Dynamic Programming technique. Try it out on your example, you may understand it better.